# is there an function for finding string in a web page by some percentage difference

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i try to find some string in a page by bs4 lib and it works good but , is there any way for find string via a percentage of diffrence like this sample :
we have this string : `The Eggplant the Witch and the Wardrobe 720p AMZN WEB-DL DD+5 1 H 264-QOQ`

and should can find this string : `The Eggplant the Witch and the Wardrobe 720p AMZN WEB-DL DD5 1 H264-QOQ`

part of my python code is :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Wsoup

x = The Eggplant the Witch and the Wardrobe 720p AMZN WEB-DL DD+5 1 H 264-QOQ
scn_rls_soup = Wsoup(my_driver, "html.parser")  

found = scn_rls_soup.find(text=x)

print(found)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html ??

Comment: are you referring to fuzzy matching?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Wsoup
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

x = "The Eggplant the Witch and the Wardrobe 720p AMZN WEB-DL DD+5 1 H 264-QOQ"
scn_rls_soup = Wsoup(my_driver, "html.parser")  

found = scn_rls_soup.findAll(text=True)
for text in found:
    if similar(x,text) > 0.8:
        print(text)
```